# Bokeh serve returns white page

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, tornado

I try to serve a bokeh app via `bokeh serve myapp.py` and the app is running at: http://localhost:5006/myapp. However, the browser shows a blank white page.

Trying to solve the issue I found the suggestion to set the environmental variable *BOKEH_RESOURCES=inline*. It doesn't change anything.

If I simply run the Python file then the returned webpage has the same address as the server app, but it is actually showing content and is responsive. Looking at the source code of the page I can see that there is a reference to https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js and the body contains data in the *application/json* script.

The server app does not contain data in the *application/json* script and references to Bokeh are like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=ac90935137e13ae0b2c6583f2e1f3fe8"></script>`

I can also see the title of the page is *Bokeh Application* while it should have the title set in myapp.py

My environment:

- centOS 7
- Bokeh 1.4.0
- Tornado 6.0.3

Comment: Are you calling `curdoc().add_root(...)` to add things to the document for display in a server app?

Comment: I'm glad it works! Can you self-answer and accept, or delete the question? (So that the [bokeh] tag does not have lingering unanswered questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion by @bigreddot I added the following code snippets to my script and called it through `bokeh serve myapp.py`.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.client import push_session

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
session = push_session(curdoc())
session.show()
```